# incorporate user messaging using firebase and swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4, chat

So I am trying to find a way to incorporate a messaging feature within an app. I cannot find any up to date information on the web, so I figured I'll ask on this platform. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

I am currently using firebase and swift as building tool for my app. I am looking to build a simple chat/messaging function where users can message each other like instagram, facebook and airbnb allows users to do.

Comment: That's an incredibly broad topic. Did you search for tutorials already? There are dozens of ["building chat on Firebase for iOS"](https://www.google.com/search?q=chat+firebase+ios) tutorials out there.

Comment: Yes I did look it up online. Again, the information is outdated. Most of the sites only provide a group chat tutorial, however I'm in search of a peer to peer messaging. I'll continue the search thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides realtime database for chatting feature and many other features where you need data updates in realtime. 
You can refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data where it shows you can handle child-added, child-changed event for realtime updates.
You will have to design your database to incorporate chats in it though and then write business logics to handle it through firebase realtime apis.